# How to set Apache-accessible SELinux policy for EFS mounted user directories?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, apache-2.4, selinux

When I [mount my EFS to a user directory](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/accessing-fs-nfs-permissions-per-user-subdirs.html), the directory policy becomes `system_u:object_r:nfs_t:s0`, which is too restrictive - I need it to behave more like a typical user directory, which is `unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_dir_t:s0`.

How do I change this?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this by [defining the context while mounting the directories](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/selinux_users_and_administrators_guide/sect-security-enhanced_linux-working_with_selinux-mounting_file_systems#sect-Security-Enhanced_Linux-Mounting_File_Systems-Multiple_NFS_Mounts). I also had to [define it in my fstab configuration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/nfs-automount-efs.html) to ensure the definition persisted after reboot. Additionally, I needed to set domain policy to httpd_sys_content_t, which allowed apache to access the content.